# clang-format and references: can I get a "true" left alignment?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I've recently tried the `ReferenceAlignment: Left` option introduced in clang-format 13.

In combination with `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true` it produces a rather strange results:

```
ShortType         & v1;
SomeLongerType    & v2;
MuchMuchLongerType& v3;
```

The `v3`'s `&` is aligned to the left, but the other two are aligned on the rightmost ampersand.

Is there a way for me to get this result instead:

```
ShortType&          v1;
SomeLongerType&     v2;
MuchMuchLongerType& v3;
```

Comment: FWIW, the `&` belongs to the variable name, not the type name so this is what I would expect the behavior to be.

Comment: I'm also using clang-format 13 and I've got `DerivePointerAlignment: false` (to not let the current format of the file influence `clang-format`), `PointerAlignment: Left` (to get `type* variable;`) and `ReferenceAlignment: Pointer` (to get references aligned like pointers). I don't get the format you get .

Comment: @TedLyngmo This happens with `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` on when you have a bunch of variables declared on subsequent lines. Do you have that situation?

Comment: @user26785 Yes, if I set `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true` along with my other settings, I get the output you desire. Perhaps you could try my whole `.clang-format` and try to find what you need from that? [Here it is](https://pastebin.com/yMg1ZyGh)

Comment: As far as I can see, whenever both pointer and reference align left, I get the right result. When pointer aligns right and reference aligns left, I get the wrong result. I'll investigate some more and maybe file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some interference between `PointerAlignment` and `ReferenceAlignment`. When they are both `Left`, I get the desired result. When the `PointerAlignment` is `Right`, I get the strange one.

```sh
$ echo "struct Test {  ShortType&          v1;  SomeLongerType&     v2;   MuchMuchLongerType& v3;};" | clang-format-13 --style "{AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, PointerAlignment: Right, ReferenceAlignment: Left}"

struct Test {
  ShortType         & v1;
  SomeLongerType    & v2;
  MuchMuchLongerType& v3;
};
$ echo "struct Test {  ShortType&          v1;  SomeLongerType&     v2;   MuchMuchLongerType& v3;};" | clang-format-13 --style "{AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, PointerAlignment: Left, ReferenceAlignment: Left}"
struct Test {
  ShortType&          v1;
  SomeLongerType&     v2;
  MuchMuchLongerType& v3;
};
```

Moreover, even when `ReferenceAlignment` is Right, the `PointerAlignment` still affects the result:

```sh
$ echo "struct Test {  ShortType&          v1;  SomeLongerType&     v2;   MuchMuchLongerType& v3;};" | clang-format-13 --style "{AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, PointerAlignment: Left, ReferenceAlignment: Right}"
struct Test {
  ShortType &         v1;
  SomeLongerType &    v2;
  MuchMuchLongerType &v3;
};
$ echo "struct Test {  ShortType&          v1;  SomeLongerType&     v2;   MuchMuchLongerType& v3;};" | clang-format-13 --style "{AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, PointerAlignment: Right, ReferenceAlignment: Right}"
struct Test {
  ShortType          &v1;
  SomeLongerType     &v2;
  MuchMuchLongerType &v3;
};
```

This may be a bug in clang-format, or it may be an expected behavior.

Comment: Nice finding. I bet testing mixed alignments isn't prio 1 since I believe it's being very unusual to have such a setup. :-)

Comment: I would rather say that the entire purpose of adding `ReferenceAlignment` was to support such a setup :) .

Comment: Filed an [issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54620), will see what happens.

Comment: _"I would rather say that the entire purpose of adding ReferenceAlignment was to support such a setup"_ - Yes, you are most probably correct. `PointerAlignment` was added in clang-format 3.7 and `ReferenceAlignment` in 13.. _"Filed an issue"_ - Very good!